# foreach JSON array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have an Array in the following format :

```
[["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","Thy","YUI"],["","",0,"jkghjg","hgjhg","kjhkjhg","kjghjkg)","gjhg","jkjkghj"]]
```

I need to "foreach" the array and get each values one by one like: Features , notes ...

When I put it into  `$.each()` I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1103' in ..
```

How do I get it?

Comment: Can you add your PHP code for `$each()` as well?

Comment: Are you sure it's an array? Usually that kind of error shown up when you try to call `$.each()` on a string. If it's a JSON response string, you can parse it like so: `JSON.parse(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var a = [["Features", "Notes", "Code", "Value", "Testing", "BAC", "Total", "Thy", "YUI"], ["", "", 0, "jkghjg", "hgjhg", "kjhkjhg", "kjghjkg)", "gjhg", "jkjkghj"]]


$.each(a, function (i, data) {
    $.each(data, function (j, val) {
        console.log(val);
    });
});
```

**you can also try this if you want to use foreach method**

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(a,function(rm){
  rm.map(function(ed){
     console.log(ed)
  })
})
```

Comment: i tried both , still i am getting error :        Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1103' in

Answer (score 0):

did you mean make the array as associative JSON object?
try this

```js
var a = [["Features", "Notes", "Code", "Value", "Testing", "BAC", "Total", "Thy", "YUI"],
         ["", "", 0, "jkghjg", "hgjhg", "kjhkjhg", "kjghjkg)", "gjhg", "jkjkghj"]]

var json = {}
for (var i in a[0]) {
  var key = a[0][i];
  var val = a[1][i];
  json[key] = val;
}
console.log(json);
console.log(json.Testing);
```

Comment: when i try this i am getting     Object {[: "["} as json console and undefined for json.Testing

Answer (score 0):

```
var a_data= [["Features","Notes","Code","Value","Testing","BAC","Total","Thy","YUI"],["","",0,"jkghjg","hgjhg","kjhkjhg","kjghjkg)","gjhg","jkjkghj"]]
var output="";
$.each(a_data,function(index,data){
   output+=data.join(",")
})
console.log(output)
```